# custom event listener on a dom node

Tags: javascript, html, custom-events

I want to dispatch an custom event in js from an element. It is like so:

```
var event = new CustomEvent("foo");
var elem = document.getElementById("bar");
elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

But I cannot bind an listener for the new custom event on a dom node. With standard events it is easy. Just add an attribute `on<eventName>="some javascript"`

```
<button onclick="console.log('click!')"></button>
```

Is it possible also with custom elements? I tried `on<elementName>` and `on-<elementName>` but it doesn't work.

```
<button onfoo="console.log('foo!')"></button>
<button on-foo="console.log('foo!')"></button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could register custom events handler using `addEventListener` method. BTW this approach is recommended for native events as well. Inline handlers are bad because they are mixing view (HTML) with logic (js).

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("bar");

elem.addEventListener('foo', function() {
  console.log('foo event on bar')
})

document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var event = new CustomEvent('foo');
  elem.dispatchEvent(event);
})
```

```html
<button id="bar">Bar</button>
<button id="foo">Trigger Foo</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Always use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of inline event listeners!

If allows you do to this:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('foo', function () {
  console.log('foo!');
});

const event = new Event('foo');
button.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: 'Always' is quite dogmatic. There are very good reasons one would use inline event handlers, though I would make them as short as possible. A good case for them if you're using a controller-based approach and wire your components together in the HTML.